# How to mapping data with text multi level?

Tags: sql, ms-access

**How to write sql statement?**

```
Table_Product
+------------------+
|     Product      |
+------------------+
|      AAA         |
|      ABB         |
|      ABC         |
|      ACC         |
+------------------+
```

```
Table_Mapping

+---------------+---------------+
|  ProductGroup |  ProductName  |
+---------------+---------------+
|     A*        |    Product1   |
|     ABC       |    Product2   |
+---------------+---------------+
```

I need the following result:

```
+------------+---------------+
|  Product   |  ProductName  |
+------------+---------------+
|    AAA     |   Product1    |
|    ABB     |   Product1    |
|    ABC     |   Product2    |
|    ACC     |   Product1    |
+------------+---------------+
```

Thanks,
TOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query does what you describe when run from within the Access application itself:

```sql
    SELECT Table_Product.Product, Table_Mapping.ProductName
    FROM
        Table_Product
        INNER JOIN
        Table_Mapping
            ON Table_Product.Product = Table_Mapping.ProductGroup
    WHERE InStr(Table_Mapping.ProductGroup, "*") = 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT Table_Product.Product, Table_Mapping.ProductName
    FROM
        Table_Product
        INNER JOIN
        Table_Mapping
            ON Table_Product.Product LIKE Table_Mapping.ProductGroup
    WHERE InStr(Table_Mapping.ProductGroup, "*") > 0
        AND Table_Product.Product NOT IN (SELECT ProductGroup FROM Table_Mapping)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: It's work for me.
Thank you very much Gord Thompson.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use CASE WHEN. Try this:

```
Select Product, (CASE
  WHEN Product = 'AAA' THEN 'Product1'
  WHEN Product = 'ABB' THEN 'Product1'
  WHEN Product = 'ABC' THEN 'Product2'
  WHEN Product = 'ACC' THEN 'Product1'
  ELSE Null END) as 'ProductName'
from Table_Product
order by Product
```

Comment: If the naming scheme for the products is more complicated or expansive, you can use something like 'WHEN Product like 'AA%', which will capture all options starting with 'AA', and so forth.

Comment: Your table mapping, though, does not make sense, as A% would also include 'ABB', which you have mapped differently.

Comment: I have product more than 10,000 record.
I can maintain table_Mapping logic about 100 record but can not maintain all products.

Comment: Dear tim_schaaf
I mapping data to present in report
some product need to show stanalone but some product need to show in group.

Answer (score 0):

If this is literally how it is uimplemented then you can

```
Select Product, ProductName
From Table_Product P
inner join Table_Mapping M
On M.Product_Group & '*' like  P.Product
```

You would have to remove change your `A*    Product` record to  `A    Product` though. I.e. you can't embed the wildcards in the record. If you want to have wildcards at the start it will run a lot slower.